# auth0 compatibility with java spring security

Tags: spring-security, auth0

Any one having experience with web application based on spring security and auth0. Tomcat is unable to pick up filters securityfilterchaining injected by auth0.

Thanks
Zubair

Comment: Suggest you get one of the Auth0 samples working first. Then evolve your own application to follow similar approach. If you get a specific issue, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Are you building an MVC web application or an API?  Auth0 has several different libraries and associated samples for each (Servlet MVC, Plain Spring MVC, Spring Security MVC, and Spring Security API). All the samples are using Tomcat. Please see links below.

### Plain Java

https://github.com/auth0/auth0-servlet

https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-servlet-sample

https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-servlet-sso-sample

### Spring MVC

https://github.com/auth0/auth0-spring-mvc

https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-spring-mvc-sample

https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-spring-mvc-passwordless-mfa-sample

https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-spring-mvc-social-db-account-link-sample

### Spring Security MVC

https://github.com/auth0/auth0-spring-security-mvc

https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-spring-security-mvc-sample

https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-spring-security-mvc-sso-sample

### Spring Security API

https://github.com/auth0/auth0-spring-security-api

https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-spring-security-api-sample

https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-spring-security-api-resource-server-sample

https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-spring-security-api-client-samples

### Grails

https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-grails2-mvc-sample

https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-grails2-spring-security-mvc-sample

https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-grails3-mvc-sample

https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-grails3-spring-security-mvc-sample

Hope this helps.

> Any one having experience with web application based on spring security and auth0

Fortunately yes, I primarily authored the above.